# Removing multiple slf4j bindings warnings didn't work

Tags: maven, slf4j

I'm trying to remove the following warning in my java project. I've tried to exclude the additional bindings I found on maven repo. But none of them worked. Any idea for resolving the issue is very much appreciated.

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/data/backup_concert/ase-core/com.aepona.iotp.parent/springboard-azure-parent/springboard-registry-app-azure/target/springboard-registry-app-azure-0.3.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.7.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/data/backup_concert/ase-core/com.aepona.iotp.parent/springboard-azure-parent/springboard-registry-app-azure/target/springboard-registry-app-azure-0.3.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/slf4j-simple-1.7.25.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Analysis of your dependency tree should set you in the right direction. The command is `mvn dependency:tree` if you are using Maven. You might want to add the output to your question for further help.

Comment: Thanks. I have added it.

Comment: The tree you posted looks incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite clear, you have both log4j-slf4j-impl-2.7.jar and slf4j-simple-1.7.25.jar, remove one of them.

Comment: I've tried to exclude them in the pom.xml file. But still the issue is there.

Comment: @A.Vindya That's not possible, you must made some mistake somewhere. You can just find the two jars in /data/backup_concert/ase-core/com.aepona.iotp.parent/springboard-azure-parent/springboard-registry-app-azure/target/springboard-registry-app-azure-0.3.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib

Comment: I can find those lib in the path. I'm trying to remove them from pom file. I tried using something like below, but it didn't work.

<exclusions>
 <exclusion>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
 </exclusion>
</exclusions>

Comment: @A.Vindya. You mush missed something. Use "mvn dependency:tree" to trace all dependencies, you have to exclude it from all the dependencies that depend on it.

Comment: Could you please tell me how to do it? I tried to do it with  <exclusions> as I mentioned above. But it didn't work.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @A.Vindya If you are sure all dependency exclude in pom, try a "mvn clean" first. And every IDE, eclipse or idea, have ways searching for maven dependency, see if you miss something to exclude